# Ruby on Rails syntax error for module definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my one of schema files built with Ruby on Rails.
When I try to run `rails db:migrate` the rails app,  I'm getting the syntax error such as

```
SyntaxError: /home/../[file_name].rb:14: module definition in method body
      module SkipCallbacks
                          ^
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

How do I have to handle this issue? Rails version: 5.2.3, ruby version: 2.5.1

```
class SetInformation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def change
    Information.all.find_each do |info|
    place = info.places.first

      module SkipCallbacks
        def run_callbacks(kind, *args, &block)
          yield(*args) if block_given?
        end
      end

        if business.physical_address.present?
           ... ...
            dup_address.extend(SkipCallbacks)
           ... ...
        end

        ... ... ... ...
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't define a module inside a method?

Comment: The error message says: "module definition in method body". Is this unclear to you? How could the error message be improved?

Comment: If the only thing you're trying to avoid is callbacks there are still gems around that do that (sneaky_save IIRC) or you can use something like `update_columns` which runs neither callbacks nor validations. It might be more helpful if you explained what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: HI, David. Thanks for your good advice. Would you explain more detail about sneaky_save IIRC? How do I have to install it?

Comment: The code works on other computer. There could be specific gems for running that kind of coding style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby regular modules cannot be defined inside methods.

You have two options:

1. Move `module SkipCallbacks` outside of `change` method into class level:

```rb
class BackfillSomeInfoToLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  module SkipCallbacks
    ...
  end

  def change
    ...
  end
end
```

2. do not move, but define it as anonymous module:

```rb
...
mod = Module.new do
  def run_callbacks(kind, *args, &block)
    yield(*args) if block_given?
  end
end
dup_physical_address.extend(mod)
...
```